# How to make table responsive after such limits?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a table in my responsive website. Table is responsive till some width. after that it will display very badly. Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully responsive table with swipe functionality;

Demo link
http://filamentgroup.github.io/tablesaw/demo/swipe.html

Source
https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw